# Pattern Matching for CSV processing

Tags: scala

I have a csv file with three columns and I want to get the third column into an Iterator. I want to filter out the headers by using the trytoDouble method in combination of the Pattern Matching.

```
def trytoDouble(s: String): Option[Double] = {
  try {
    Some(s.toDouble)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => None
  }
}

val asdf = Source.fromFile("my.csv").getLines().map(_.split(",").map(_.trim).map(utils.trytoDouble(_))).map{
  _ match {
    case Array(a, b, Some(c: Double)) => c
  }
}
```

results in

> An exception or error caused a run to abort: [Lscala.Option;@2b4a2ec7 (of class [Lscala.Option;) 
>   scala.MatchError: [Lscala.Option;@2b4a2ec7 (of class [Lscala.Option;)

what did I do wrong?

Comment: which field you want to apply tryToDouble?? seems you are applying on all. Actually your problem is matching the result. Probably your tryToDouble returns None.

Comment: @prayagupd: I know I apply `tryToDouble` to all fields. I think this should not matter: `a, b` are not defined in type in the pattern matching, so they should fit always. Regarding `c`: Of course `None` is returned sometimes - that is the point ;-). If that is the case, I want that the line is ignored - filtered out if you will. Maybe I need to use something different than `map`?

Comment: That is breaking code anyway because your match does not handle a case when the third column is `None`. What if csv is `("a", "b", "c")`. See my answer if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [*extractor*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html) like `StringDouble` below. If the `unapply` returns `Some` then it matches, if it returns `None` then it doesn't match.

```
object StringDouble {
  def unapply(str: String): Option[Double] = Try(str.toDouble).toOption
}

val doubles =
  Source.fromFile("my.csv").getLines().map { line =>
    line.split(",").map(_.trim)
  }.map {
    case Array(_, _, StringDouble(d)) => d
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**having only one match case is always breaking code.**

See the REPL example,

```
scala> def trytoDouble(s: String): Option[Double] = {
     |   try {
     |     Some(s.toDouble)
     |   } catch {
     |     case e: Exception => None
     |   }
     | }
```

**when there's no Double in your CSV,**

```
scala> List("a,b,c").map(_.split(",").map(_.trim).map(trytoDouble(_)))
res1:  List[Array[Option[Double]]] = List(Array(None, None, None))
```

When you match above result (`Array(None, None, None)`) with `Array(a, b, Some(c: Double))` always going to fail,

```
scala> List("a,b,c").map(_.split(",").map(_.trim).map(trytoDouble(_))).map { data => 
     | data match {
     |     case Array(a, b, Some(c: Double)) => c
     | }
     | }
scala.MatchError: [Lscala.Option;@22604c7e (of class [Lscala.Option;)
  at .$anonfun$res4$4(<console>:15)
  at .$anonfun$res4$4$adapted(<console>:13)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:283)
  ... 33 elided
```

**And when there Double,**

```
scala> List("a,b,100").map(_.split(",").map(_.trim).map(trytoDouble(_))).map { data => data match { case Array(a, b, Some(c: Double)) => c }}
res5: List[Double] = List(100.0)
```

**You basically need to check for Some(c) or None.**

BUT, if I understand you you are to extract third field as Double which can be done this way,

```
scala> List("a,b,100", "100, 200, p").map(_.split(",")).map { case Array(a, b, c) => trytoDouble(c)}.filter(_.nonEmpty)
res14: List[Option[Double]] = List(Some(100.0))
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very interesting! But how do I get a `List[Double]` instead of `List[Option[Double]]` as a result?

Comment: Don't know how your are solving, but to convert `List[Option][Double]` to `List[Double]` is flatMap. you simply can flatten `List(Some(3), Some(1)).flatten` will you give `List(3, 1)`. flatten simply gives you the outermost type. Equivalent to `List(Some(3), Some(1)).flatMap(x => x)`

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling I need something like that, that is why I commented "Maybe I need to use something different than map?" :-D. Actually we can just make the last `map` into a `flatMap`. I'll explain in more detail in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It will always give `scala.MatchError`

```
scala> val url = "/home/knoldus/data/moviedataset.csv"
url: String = /home/knoldus/data/moviedataset.csv

scala> val asdf1 = Source.fromFile(url).getLines().map(_.split(",").map(_.trim).map(trytoDouble(_))).toList
asdf1: List[Array[Option[Double]]] = List(Array(Some(1.0), None, Some(1993.0), Some(3.9), Some(4568.0)), Array(Some(2.0), None, Some(1932.0), Some(3.5), Some(4388.0)), Array(Some(3.0), None, Some(1921.0), Some(3.2), Some(9062.0)), Array(Some(4.0), None, Some(1991.0), Some(2.8), Some(6150.0)), Array(Some(5.0), None, Some(1963.0), Some(2.8), Some(5126.0)), ....
```

As it will return non-empty iterator so, to see the result i have converted it toList.
If you notice return type is `List[Array[Option[Double]]]`, and you are trying to match with Array of tuple3 but it always returns `Array[Option[Double]]`.
Therefore, it will always throw error.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
    `val asdf = Array("1,2,3","1,b,c").map(_.split(",").map(_.trim).map(trytoDouble(_))).map{
      _(2) match {
        case x:Option[Double] => x
      }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great, but I just noticed that an alternative of minimal code change is to simply write

```
val asdf = Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().map(_.split(",").map(_.trim).map( utils.trytoDouble(_))).flatMap{
  _ match {
    case Array(a, b, c) => c
  }
}
```

or slightly more efficient (since we are only interested in the last column anyway):

```
val asdf = Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().map(_.split(",")).flatMap{
  _ match {
    case Array(a, b, c) => trytoDouble(c.trim)
  }
}
```

Important to notice is here that `flatMap` will remove `None` objects.